# Show select on product display even for 1 referenced product

Tags: 7, commerce

In Drupal Commerce (D7), when multiple products are referenced by a product display, they appear on the product display as a select list, but I can also choose radio buttons.

The trouble is, some of my products displays reference one product and some reference multiple. If I only reference one product, there is no select list or radio button. In other words:

Product 1: "black", "red", "blue"
Product 2: "red"

On product 1's page, there will be options for all 3 colors
On product 2's page, there will be no color options.

Even though you can't choose from more than one options with product 2, I still want the select list/radio button to display so customers know what color option is available.

How would I do this?

Comment: I thought I dug enough before posting here, but here's the answer:

Drupal Commerce 1.5+ includes this feature now (I was running 1.4). And DC 1.5+ requires Drupal 1.15+ (I was still on 1.14 so didn't see the DC 1.5 update).

In the product display, go to the field display settings, hit the gear icon for the "add to cart form", then put a check beside "Show attribute widgets even if the Add to Cart form only represents one product".

Simple (one you find the answer)!

Comment: after couple of days you should be able to post your comment as an answer to your own question and mark the question solved.

Comment: hi Eric have a look on (http://eurekaselect.com/51944/volume/1). do you need something like that.